# A View Model for App.Xaml

Tags: wpf, mvvm, app.xaml

Can we have a viewModel for App.Xaml so that we can do some logical deductions on startUp and also form a starting point of app...

Comment: But App.xaml isn't really a "view" in the sense of the word, is it...

Answer (score 3):

No, App.xaml is not a Window class, it is your Application class.

You can still overwrite the `OnStartup()` method of it to handle your own custom logic and to startup specific Views/ViewModels.

For example,

```cs
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);

    var login = new LoginDialog();
    var loginVm = new LoginViewModel();

    login.DataContext = loginVm;
    login.ShowDialog();

    if (!login.DialogResult.GetValueOrDefault())
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }

    // Providing we have a successful login, startup application
    var app = new ShellView();
    var context = new ShellViewModel(loginVm.CurrentUser);
    app.DataContext = context;
    app.Show();
}
```

Comment: I got your point then how will i handle this situation [Toggle views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656743/toggle-two-views-windows-in-mvvm-wpf)

Comment: The `ShellViewModel` would handle whatever view is `Current`, just like the top answer to your question said. Here's another example of switching Views: http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/28/switching-between-viewsusercontrols-using-mvvm/

Answer (score 1):

No we cannot have view models at App level. As @BoltClock suggested, It isnt something that has a data context to which we bind an instance of any class. MVVM does not work with `App`.

Comment: So how will i open a "view" based on CommandLine Arguments supplied

Comment: Views are actually 2 Windows i.e the application can open in 2 modes

Comment: Application class has a static `Main()` method isnt it? That will accept your command line parameters and based on that it will create a window and launch its contents using `GetContentStream()` call.