# Toggle two views (Windows) in MVVM WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am developing an application which has 2 Modes

1. Configuration  Mode
2. Execution Mode

Boths modes will open in new window. I have already made the configuration Window.

I need to switch between 2 Modes by pressing `Key F12` or something like that.... also i have to prompt the user for password while switching from Execution to configutation mode (Just once durnig the session) i have made the password screen and implemented in configuration.

I am also worried as i have used Messenger(Meaditor pattern) so closing and opening of 2 different windows will register the delegates again nad again... and i am launching `Modal windows`.

Also do we need to keep both the Views alive or i can kill one of them on toggling.

Totally confused about the implementation...

My App.Xaml Code

```
 /// <summary>
    ///   Application_Startup
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name = "sender"></param>
    /// <param name = "e"></param>
    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        log.Debug("Application_Startup  " + Utility.FUNCTION_ENTERED_LOG);
        try
        {

                if (e.Args.Length == 0)
                {
                    AboutDialog.SpashScreen(Utility.TOOL_NAME,
                                            Utility.TOOL_VERSION);
                    MainView mainForm = new MainView();
                    mainForm.ShowDialog();
                }
                else
                {
                    string key = null;
                    foreach (string arg in e.Args)
                    {
                        if (arg.StartsWith("-"))
                        {
                            //this is a key         
                            key = arg;
                            if (key.Equals("-config"))
                            {
                                CommandLineArgs.Add(key, "config");
                                break;
                            }
                            if (key.Equals("-start"))
                            {
                                CommandLineArgs.Add(key, "start");
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //should be a value        
                            if (key == null)
                            {
                                throw new Exception(
                                    "The command line arguments are malformed.");
                            }
                            CommandLineArgs.Add(key, arg);
                            key = null;
                        }
                    }
                    string config = string.Empty;
                    foreach (object k in App.CommandLineArgs.Keys)
                    {
                        config += CommandLineArgs[k].ToString();
                    }

                    switch (config)
                    {
                        case "config":
                            AboutDialog.SpashScreen(
                                Utility.TOOL_NAME,
                                Utility.TOOL_VERSION);
                            MainView mainForm = new MainView();
                            mainForm.ShowDialog();
                            break;
                         case "start" :
                               ExecutionForm execuForm= new ExecutionForm();
                               execuForm.ShowDialog();
                               break;
                        default:
                            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Parameters",
                                            Utility.TOOL_NAME);
                            Application.Current.Shutdown();
                            break;
                    }

            }
            log.Debug("Application_Startup" + Utility.FUNCTION_EXIT_LOG);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {              
            log.Error("Application_Startup" + ex.Message, ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the down vote .... but atleast have the courtesy to tell me why...

Comment: There's no real question here, apart from some code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your implementation doesnt look totally wrong to me.

If I am given a requirement to swtich between two views on a modal window by a key press then I would have gone the MVVM way...

1. Use single modal window that hosts multiple contents situationally.
2. Have a `ContentControl` on the Window. Bind the `Content` to the `DataContext`.

   ```
   <DockPanel LastChildFill="true">
       <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" ...>
       </Menu>
       <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" ... />
   </DockPanel>
   ```
3. Create two data templates as resources. One data template corresponds to the view of "Config" and other data template is for 'Execution" view.

   ```
   <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ConfigView" ... />
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ExecutionView" ... />
   </Window.Resources>
   ```

You can keep these data templates in different resources files and merge the resource dictionaries to the window resources.

1. Create a single ViewModel with a writeable `Mode` property. Have INotifyPropertyChanged implemented.

   ```
   public class ViewModel : INotifPropertyChanged
   {
       private string mode;

       public string Mode
       {
            get  { return mode; }
            set  { mode = value; NotifPropertyChanged("Mode"); }
       }

       private IComamnd changeModeCommand;

       public ICommand ChangeModeCommand
       {
           get
           {
               if (changeModeCommand == null)
                    changeModeCommand
                       = new DelegateCommand(
                            OnModeChange,
                            CanModeChange);
               return changeModeCommand;
           }
       }

       //// Other properties and functions go here ...
   }
   ```

In the code above `DelegateCommand` is not internally found in .Net APIs. Get their implementation from the internet.

1. Register a `KeyBinding` for `F12` on the window. The `Command` for F12 `KeyBinding` comes from the `ViewModel`.

   ```
   <Window.InputBindings>
       <KeyBinding Command="{Binding ChangeModeCommand}"
                   Key="F12" />
   </Window.InputBindings>
   ```

In versions prior to .Net 4.0, the `Command` property is not bindable. use [CommandReference](http://joyfulwpf.blogspot.com/2009/05/mvvm-commandreference-and-keybinding.html) for this.

1. OnModeChange() for `F12` key, switch the `Mode` from `ViewModel` class and raise property changed Notification.
2. Have data triggers on the `ContentControl` on the `Window`. In the data triggers check `Mode` if it is "Config" and change the `ContentTemplate` to "Config" data template othwerise change to "Execution" datatemplate.

   ```
      <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
       <ContentControl.Style>
           <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
               <Style.Triggers>
                   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Mode}" Value="Config">
                       <Setter Property="ContentTemplate"
                               Value="{StaticResource ConfigView}"/>
                   </DataTrigger>
                   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Mode}" Value="Execution">
                       <Setter Property="ContentTemplate"
                               Value="{StaticResource ExecutionView}"/>
                   </DataTrigger>
               </Style.Triggers>
           </Style>
       </ContentControl.Style>
     </ContentControl>
   ```

I hope my way helps you in some sense.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that and cme back to you... :)

Comment: Sure. Dont forget to set the instance of the `ViewModel` as a `DataContext` to the `Window`. :-)

Comment: I tried your way it works but the `MenuBar` is  different for both Views?? how to handle that.... a different MenuBar for each view or...... there is some other way

Comment: Wrap your `ContentControl` with a `DockPanel` and Dock a `Menu` to the Top. If menu items change based on `Mode` then change them based on similar data triggers under `Menu.Style`.